# Pass input parameters to script from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a python script provided by a file from a Jupyter notebook. The script is running if I use the following command:

```py
!python script.py --input_path /folder/input --output_path /folder/output/
```

But I need to pass those paths from a variable of my notebook. How can I do it?

Tried this but it didn't work:

```py
input = "/folder/input"
output = "/folder/output/"

!python script.py --input_path input --output_path output
```

Comment: You should ideally `import script`, then call it rather than using Jupyter to run a shell command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values can be passed through to the shell command using the `{}` notation. See [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Passing-Values-to-and-from-the-Shell) link for additional handling between the Python runtime and shell commands.

For example:

```py
input = "/folder/input"
output = "/folder/output/"

!echo python script.py --input_path "{input}" --output_path "{output}"
```

Prints the following output:

```
python script.py --input_path "/folder/input" --output_path "/folder/output/"
```

Obviously, the `echo` can be removed to make it actually invoke the `python` command, which is what the original question is after.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be OK to use the subprocess package? Here I am running a script in the same folder as the notebook. It works well.

```
import subprocess
input_file = '/folder/input'
output_file = '/folder/output'
subprocess.run('python script.py --input_path {} --output_path {}'.format(input_file, output_file))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$` sign to access Python variables.

```
input = "/folder/input"
output = "/folder/output/"

!python script.py --input_path $input --output_path $output
```