# Passing arguments (NumPy array) to a Python script in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, parameter-passing, numpy-ndarray

I have a Python script that is being executed through a Jupyter Notebook running on VScode. I am running it using the run magic command. The script needs some NumPy arrays and strings as inputs, these arrays are stored as Jupiter variables. I though that using `args = sys.argv` was enough, but when debugging I realised that the args inside the script are actually the strings passed as inputs and not the arrays stored under those names. For instance in

```
%run myScript string1 string2 NumpyArray1
```

the variable inside the script is the string "NumpyArray1" and not the array stored with the name "NumpyArray1" in the Jupyter:variables of the notebook. 'NumpyArray1' is a 2D matrix (432x532)

Can someone explain to me how to pass an array as input to the script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass input parameters to script from jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287110/pass-input-parameters-to-script-from-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @Jeanot this comes close, but for some reason just the first element of the variable "NumpyArray1" (which is an array with hundreds of values) are passed through....

Comment: present the entire situation. likely "running a subprocess" is a bad and wrong solution and should not be made to work. you should import that script and call functions contained within it, passing your data in.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it is a script running some multiprocessing functions. For many reasons I am unable to run multiprocessing on a Jupyter notebook so I have this script and use the notebook just to automatise the process avoiding using the terminal. I believe my multiprocessing will not work if imported...

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pass an array as a command line argument (not on a very elegant way at least). What you can do, is giving the command line a a bunch of numbers separated by comma without brackets.

```
python myScript 3,1,4, etc.
```

Afterwards, just use a simple split on the argv[] like below

```
import sys
arr = sys.argv[1].split(',')
print(arr[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I think this will not work since 'NumpyArray1" is a 2D matrix with hundreds of values

Comment: Oh, I did not read you were working with 2d-array. Kindly update your post and in the meantime, I will update my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to automate

```
#python script.py '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'

import numpy as np
import sys
import numpy as np

def numpy_array_to_csv_string(np_array):
    csv_string = np.array2string(np_array, separator=',')
    return csv_string[1:-1]  # Remove the surrounding square brackets

def process_csv(csv_string):
    # Convert the CSV string back to a NumPy array
    np_array = np.fromstring(csv_string, sep=',')
    
    # Reshape the array if necessary (e.g., if it was a 2D array)
    # np_array = np_array.reshape((num_rows, num_columns))
    
    # Do whatever processing you want with the NumPy array here
    print("NumPy Array:")
    print(np_array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python script.py 'csv_data'")
    else:
        csv_data = sys.argv[1]
        process_csv(csv_data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).